# JSON to Spring Controller with POJO and Enum

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

I need to map something like this:

JSON:

```
{'field1': 'value1', 'provider': {'name': 'nameprov', 'country': 'CODE'}}
```

to a Spring MVC controller:

```
@ResponseBody
Dummy getVal(@RequestBody MyCriteria criteria) {
```

Where MyCriteria, in fact, is a class that extends this:

```
public abstract class MyCriteria {
  String field1;
  //Getter and setter
  Provider provider;
  //Getter and setter
}
```

But Provider has an enum inside:

```
public class Provider{
  String name;
  Country country; //Country is an Enum
```

So, I created some converters but it does not work.

I added them to web config:

```
@Override
public void addFormatters (FormatterRegistry registry) {
    registry.addConverter(new StringToCountryConverter());
    registry.addConverter(new StringToProviderConverter());
}
```

String to Country:

```
public Country convert(String s) {
    //It never enters here
}
```

and String to Provider:

```
@Override
public Provider convert(String[] s) {

    //never here

}
```

So my question is: What I am doing wrong? I need to map a string to Country, and later to Provider, but I have this error:

```
Could not read document: Can not construct instance of ...Provider: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value...
```

Provider has this constructors:

```
public Provider(String name, String country) 
public Provider(String name, Country country)
```

Any clue, will be grateful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a default constructor for the Provider class, like

```
public Provider() {}
```

Comment: Oh! Thanks! In addition, as I suspected, all the converters were not necessary to achieve the correct mapping.